# Update array item in dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

In my **dynamoDB**, I have a table that structure as like as given below:

```
 var params = {
      "TableName" : "pdfs",
      "Item" : {
          pdfid:  // Partition key
          html: [] // array attribute
       }
 };
```

I can insert new array data, just like as given code:

**Insert array data**

```
 var params = {
      "TableName" : "pdfs",
      "Item" : {
          pdfid: pdfid,
          html: [event.html]   // here "html" is an array, I just insert first array data
       }
 };

 dc.put(params, function(err, data) {
     ............................
 });
```

How can I update array in `dynamoDB` ?

```
  var params = {
      TableName: "pdfs",
      Key: {
         pdfid: event.pdfid
      },
      UpdateExpression: "SET html = :html",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":html": ??????
      },
      ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };
```

Comment: If html is an array of Strings, then you should use StringSet data type, and then use ADD in the UpdateExpression

Answer (score 5):

Use the following UpdateExpression to append values to a list: `SET html = list_append(html, :html)`. The ExpressionAttributeValues would just be a mapping from `:html` to the string that you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Use the String Set attribute to update the list.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":html": {
              SS: aws.StringSlice(your_html_array)    
      }
```